# How to handle weights in onMeasue for custom views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-layout-weight

I have a custom view which I'm creating that will scale the font size of its child `TextViews` to fit all in a set width, so each is on its own line. Obviously it's going to need the width to figure that out.

I had overridden `onMeasure()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
  int lineWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

  // Change the text size until the largest line of text fits.
  while (lineWidth < calculateTextWidth()) {
    for (TextView textView : this.childViews) {
      float newSize = textView.getTextSize() - 1;
      textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, newSize);
    }
  }

  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

`calculateTextWidth()` calculates the width of the largest line of text and everything works with that. This code is working fine for `FILL_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` widths, but screws up when I try to give the component a weight and let it auto-set its weight that way.

`MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)` returns `0`, as `getMinimumSuggestedWidth()` does, too. This gives a wonderful Activity Not Responding error, since lineWidth will always be less than `calculateTextWidth()` would ever return, so the `while` loop runs forever. The XML code I used was this, essentially:

```
<com.my.widgets.ScalingTextViewGroup
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:text="Text 3"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:text="Text 4"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</com.my.widgets.ScalingTextViewGroup>
```

I understand why it's returning 0 - obviously, it's being set to 0 - but how do I get it to use the `layout_weight`? I feel like it's something that should have a simple answer, but I'm at a loss as to what it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out through some significant Googling. On [this page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http://cafebabe.sinaapp.com/?cat=16) I found out that **onMeasure is actually called twice** when `android:layout_weight` is set. I found out later that it's mentioned in [How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) that `measure()` can be called any number of times, it just didn't immediately sit in my brain. The first pass obviously can't give a value for the size of each child, since it doesn't know what the weights of all of the View's siblings are. It goes through it once and gives a width of 0 with a MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED to see if the child has any specific constraints, then goes through *again* to assign the actual weights with a MeasureSpec.EXACTLY. My Activity was getting screwed up at the first pass, so it never got to the layout step. Amending my onMeasure() to the following code fixed the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
  if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int lineWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

    // Change the text size until the largest line of text fits.
    while (lineWidth < calculateTextWidth()) {
      for (TextView textView : this.childViews) {
        float newSize = textView.getTextSize() - 1;
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, newSize);
      }
    }
  }

  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: So if you had stopped before the while loop you would have the max available size given the weight you specified?  (Going to read your links now...)